# Qt-Creator: output messages on a per-file-compile basis?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

**Qt 5.8.0, Qt Creator 4.2.2, OSX 10.12.6, CLang**

When Qt builds my project, it dutifully dumps all the compile invocation information to the `4 Compile Output` pane. This is a *lot* of text, and it scrolls by pretty fast, sometimes so fast I can't keep track of which file it is building, or has built.

There's a `6 General Messages` pane that receives messages as set up in the project's `project.pro` file. For instance, putting the following command at the end of the `.pro` file results in an immediate dump to the `6 General Messages` pane as soon as the .pro file is processed...

`message(This is a test)`

...so what I'd like to do, if possible, is modify the built in compiler variable to output a message to the `6 General Messages` window *as each individual file is compiled.* I imagine it might go something like this...

`CC += message($$FILENAME)`

... where `FILENAME` is a placeholder for the actual variable name for the file being passed to the compiler to build. I have no idea exactly what the syntax or variable names might actually be, presuming this is possible at all. Any insight regarding this objective is most welcome.

Comment: I added a tag for `Qt-Creator` since the question appears to be about the IDE and not the `Qt` framework.

Comment: drescherjm: Thank you